# Como chamar a API da receita federal com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou criando uma API REST e na hora de cadastrar a empresa gostaria de informar apenas o CNPJ, então usar a receita WS pra trazer os dados da empresa.

Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
const Empresa = require('../models/Empresa');

module.exports = {
    async index(req, res) { }

    async store(req, res) {
        const cnpj = req.body;
        daqui eu pegaria esse cnpj e chamaria a Receita WS
    }
}
```

Comment: E qual código você já fez?

Comment: const Empresa = require('../models/Empresa');

module.exports = {
    async index(req, res) {

    },
    async store(req, res) {
        const cnpj = req.body;
    }
}

Comment: Edite na pergunta por gentileza

Comment: não entendi... desculpa

Comment: Inclua o código na sua pergunta, não no comentário. Tente montar um [MVCE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Segue dicas: É complicado devido ao *captcha*, mas é possível automatizar isso. Caso queira algo mais simples, o governo tem uma [API](https://servicos.serpro.gov.br/api-serpro/biblioteca/consulta-cnpj/index.html) para consultas de CNPJ. Você também pode usar o serviço do site [Receita WS](https://receitaws.com.br/pricing) ou ainda usar técnicas de `crawler` na Internet.